# Extracting file persmission data in Ansible

Tags: acl, ansible, ansible-awx

I want to build a playbook to check File permissions of all the files in a directory and then create a report containing its details using Ansible.

I tried using ACL module for this purpose but I can't understand where is the return list getting stored ?

Answer (score 1):

As the examples for the [ACL module](http://docs.ansible.com/acl_module.html) show:

```
# Obtain the acl for a specific file
- acl: name=/etc/foo.conf
  register: acl_info
```

To then look at the results:

```
- debug: var=acl_info
```

That should get you started.  The debug task will display the full results of what was retrieved by the acl module.

Answer (score 0):

Ansible files module - find command can list all the files in a directory with the file permissions

```
    tasks:
  - name: list of files
    find: paths="/tmp" recurse=yes file_type=file
    register: list_of_files
  - debug: msg="{{ list_of_files.files }}"
```

The result will have the mode of the file say 0777 or 0600 etc.

Comment: I tried using find module before . It returns me an error " find is not a legal parameter in an Ansible task or handler" .

Comment: Is it possible for you to upgrade ansible? Find command will then work http://docs.ansible.com/find_module.html -- if not, acl is the option. The code snippet which Bruce P has answered should work.